# Rewrite Magento url to Wordpress page

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, magento, mod-rewrite

I have a Magento site installed at the root of my domain and a Wordpress installed in a subdirectory. Currently I access my sites like this:

- Magento: "domain.com"
- Wordpress: "domain.com/blog"

I would like to be able to use Wordpress **Pages** seamlessly, without the "/blog" subdirectory showing in the url, such as:

Wordpress Page-X: "domain.com/page-x"

Note that **I do want to keep the "/blog" subdirectory showing normally for blog posts** etc... I just don't want it for Wordpress Pages.

Could anybody help on how to set that up? I was think tweaking the .htaccess would've work, but I can't find out how. Other solutions are welcome too. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Magento provides you with an option to create custom URL rewrites in the backend (admin) you can [find](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/modules_reference/english/mage_adminhtml/urlrewrite/index) it here. This way you should be able to create rewrites. Also if you want to automate the creation of rewrites you can refer to the core_rewrites table in magento's database. Also [this](http://alanstorm.com/magento_dispatch_rewrites_intro) is a good read if you want to do logic based rewrites on the fly.